# Math Piecewise style, which one is correct/best?

Tags: notation

I am writing my Computer Science Master Thesis. I am wondering what is the correct or in your opinion best looking style for piecewises:

See examples below:

1. Do I use a comma at the end of each line (ex last line)?
2. Do I end the last line with a dot?
3. Do I use a separator, and if yes which (in this example a colon) to seperate condition and formula?
4. What other things are stylewise wrong in the example below?

$$f(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0 & : x \leq 0, \\
       1 & : x > 0. 
     \end{array}
   \right.$$

Comment: Instead of the colon, how about the word "if"?  Never really hurts to say what you mean ;-)

Comment: If this is a computer science thesis, why are you asking here? Conventions may differ between different fields.

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & \text{if $x<0$;} \\ 
    1, & \text{if $x\geq 0$.}\end{cases}$$
```

resulting in

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & \text{if $x<0$;} \\ 
1, & \text{if $x\geq 0$.}\end{cases}$$

IIRC this was also suggested by the authors of AMSmath.

Answer (score 0):

I usually would write with a semicolon, so $$\begin{cases}0;& x\leq 0\\ 1;& x>0\end{cases}$$ but it's a matter of preference. I remember having the same question, I just asked my supervisor.

Comment: Wow, a downvote? What's so bad about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use an array command; there already exists the cases environment which takes care of the brackets etc.:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x<0, \\ 1, & x\geq 1.\end{cases}$$

I personally would use a colon as the separator, but these style-questions shouldn't really matter. If you want to be absolutely sure ask your supervisor.

Comment: Also note that you can use `\cases{...}` instead of `\begin{cases}...\end{cases}`

Comment: @Arthur you're right, but I always choose to use \begin...\end with any environment. I find it much easier to read and find mistakes in the code.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score -1):

Best practice is to ask your master's thesis supervisor if your Computer Science department has a required/recommended LaTeX style/class file that you should/could use for writing up your master's thesis as a whole (and that's not just for piecewise definitions of functions).  If said file is not available, ask your CS department for the thesis layout guidelines, if there are any.